# Очистка памяти при COM соединении

Tags: java, com, outlook

Я подключаюсь к `Outlook` через `Jacob`. Все было бы хорошо. Но при переборе почты, он похоже не выгружает их сам. (У почтового клиента явно видна утечка памяти) И это при том что объекты `ActiveXComponent`не хранятся долгосрочно.

Можно ли провести явную выгрузку из памяти и отключение от приложения?

Comment: Хотел возмутиться, что никто не читает маны - но не смог найти этих самых манов в инете...

Comment: Попробуйте Jawin вместо Jacob - там документация хотя бы есть.